# About another Application to visit SharedPreference

Tags: android

I need visit the sharedPreference of another application, the `SharedPreference` have to set

`"MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE|MODE_WORLD_READABLE"` , and show you the Logcat.

```
03-23 13:54:45.038: E/ApplicationContext(10895): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.mzw.gamehelper/shared_prefs/public.xml to backup file /data/data/com.mzw.gamehelper/shared_prefs/public.xml.bak
```

I dont know what's wrong with it, who can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code insert values

```
 private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    myPrefs = Actionactivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("Mobile_no", getText_no.getText().toString().trim());
    prefsEditor.commit();
```

and try this code get values

```
myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
myPrefs.getString("Mobile_no", "");
```

Comment: I can get the values,it's ok, but can't to change the value,throw the Exception .

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS WAY ::

```
Context otherAppsContext = null;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String PREFS_READ = "PREFS_READ";
public static final String KEY_READ = "KEY_READ";
try {
  //com.dfdf.fdfdf.android.sharedpreferences OTHER APPLICTION PACKAGE NAME
       otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("com.dfdf.fdfdf.android.sharedpreferences", 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }
 sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_READ, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
 String strvalue=sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_READ, "WORLD READ EMPTY")
```

Comment: mContext = this.createPackageContext(packName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
  SharedPreferences spf2 = mContext.getSharedPreferences("public",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE|MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
  
        Editor editor = spf2.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("preview", true);
  editor.putInt("overlay_size", 100);
  editor.commit();